# Pass results from one factory/service ajax method to another via the controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have two ajax calls in a service; the first one, `AjaxOne` gets the data I want from `fields` (user entered), I then want to alter the data by passing it to another ajax call, `AjaxTwo` to get the results I need. Both ajax calls are completely different services and can be interacted with by multiple controllers so I've placed then in their own unique Angular `factory` methods (could be `service`).

Issue is I'm thinking traditional sequential code running akin to PHP in my little semi-sudo code below (which I know will not work but just for example of how I would solve it in PHP), but I know I need to be thinking in parallel but can't quite get my head around what I need to do for the controller to be able to pass the results from `AjaxOne` to `AjaxTwo`. Keep in mind that both `factory` methods don't need to know of each other existence (to create no coupling and make then highly reusable).

How would I go about doing what I need to with Angular?

```
app.controller('app', function( $http, $scope, AjaxOne, AjaxTwo ) {

    $scope.fields  = '';
    $scope.ajaxOne = AjaxOne;
    $scope.ajaxTwo = AjaxTwo;
    $scope.results = [];

    $scope.process = function () {
        AjaxOne.getResults($scope.fields);
        $scope.results = AjaxTwo.getResults(AjaxOne.results);
    };

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to post the code for `.getResults()` for both `AjaxOne` & `AjaxTwo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to adjust your `AjaxOne` service to accept a callback, which would asynchronously call `AjaxTwo` only when `AjaxOne` is done doing whatever it does:

```
// Inside AjaxOne:

$scope.getResults = function(things, cb) {
  // do something with `things`. Let's assume you're using $http:
  $http({
    url: "http://example.appspot.com/rest/app",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    cb(data);
  });
};

// In your original example:

app.controller('app', function($http, $scope, AjaxOne, AjaxTwo) {

  $scope.fields = '';
  $scope.ajaxOne = AjaxOne;
  $scope.ajaxTwo = AjaxTwo;
  $scope.results = [];

  $scope.process = function() {
    AjaxOne.getResults($scope.fields, function(resultsFromAjaxOne) {
      $scope.results = AjaxTwo.getResults(resultsFromAjaxOne);
    });
  };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the promises that you get with the $http service it will give something like this

```
app.controller('app', function( $http, $scope, AjaxOne, AjaxTwo ) {

$scope.fields  = '';
$scope.results = [];

$scope.process = function () {
    AjaxOne.getResults($scope.fields).success(function(results){
        AjaxTwo.getResults(results).success(function(results2){
            $scope.results = results2;
        });
    });

};
```

});

for more information you can check this url http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http